# Pushwoosh notification without sound

Tags: pushwoosh

How can we send pushnotification without sound using pushwoosh php API

below is my code

```
pwCall('createMessage', array(
    'application' => PW_APPLICATION,
    'auth' => PW_AUTH,
    'notifications' => array(
            array(
                'send_date' => 'now',
                'content' => $podcast_title,
                'data' => array('custom' => json_encode($cus_data)),
                'link' => 'https://bnc.lt/castbox',
                'ios_sound' =>'',
                'android_sound' =>'silent.wav',
                'platforms'=>array(3),
                //'devices'=>array('f82759fc4ca672e27bae0a509710167f52e24577db6d4b5da87e51f8b9ab3b47'),             
                //'conditions'=>array(array($tag,"EQ",$filter_name)),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a push without a sound to iOS devices you should just not specify any sound in `'ios_sound'`.

For Android just use the `'android_sound'` without a value: `'android_sound'=>''`.

Otherwise you can put a soundless file to your app package and play it when you need it.